# mysql transpose dynamic dates from rows to column with join tables and count

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

**Users**

```
id | driverId | name
```

**Drivers**

```
id | userID
```

**Jobs**

```
id | driverID | created_at
```

So want total jobs count by user and by date (the job is created) also.

Result format would be:-

```
userID | 2019-05-11 | 2019-04-11 (created_at of job as column) ..........
1      | 2          | 5
2      | 10         | 4
```

I have tried with below query:-

```
SELECT
    COUNT(jobs.id) AS TotalJobs,
    DATE(jobs.created_at) AS created_at,
    users.id AS userID,
    users.first_name,
    users.last_name,
    jobs.driver_id AS jobsDriverID
FROM
    `jobs`
JOIN users ON users.driver_id = jobs.driver_id
GROUP BY
    DATE(jobs.created_at),
    users.driver_id
ORDER BY
    users.id ASC
```

And got this result but not exactly as I want.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a *static* column list (ie over a pre-defined list of days), or for something entirely dynamic? If you want the second option, then you would need dynamic SQL, which is much more complex.

Comment: No it should be date on which the job is created.it is fully dynamic columns of dates with jobs count.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry is right for smaller tables this is better handled by the application...

Comment: I think I'm right regardless of the size of the table!

Comment: @kinjaljethva this means that you need dynamic sql.

Comment: *"I think I'm right regardless of the size of the table!"* Well i am pretty sure you dont want to transfer very big resultsets (like 1 Gb+) on "every" request  to the application to pivot @Strawberry

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm pretty sure you don't want to render a thousand columns to the mysql CLI.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure you don't want to render a thousand columns to the mysql CLI. "* @Strawberry , i am pretty sure i would use a "materialized" view approach to generate that pivot for the application code depening if i can get away with showing a bit older data..  Anyhow we are moving way to much offtopic with unrelated comments as we don't know if a programming language  or MySQL CLI is involved.. ..

Comment: I resolved it thanks.